# how to make content script in google chrome extension execute only after user clicks on extension's button

Tags: google-chrome

I want that a content script executes only after user clicks on the toolbar button for that extension (and not before).. I want some forms in child iframes to be fully loaded, after that the user should click on the button, and now the content script will send contents of the child iframes in message to the background page of the extension.

Is it possible to do this? How to implement it?

Answer (score 3):

Use Programmatic Injection. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

```
/* in background.html */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
});

/* in manifest.json */
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```

this will execute a content script everytime the extension is clicked.

Comment: how to achieve this in manifest version 3 ?